# SIP Generator Error Installing ROS Melodic on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, linux, qt, sip

I've been attempting to install ROS Melodic on my Raspberry Pi 4 (running Raspbian Stretch) according to the instructions on this webpage:

[https://www.instructables.com/id/ROS-Melodic-on-Raspberry-Pi-4-RPLIDAR/][1]

However, when building the catkin packages, I get this error:

```
[ 89%] Built target qt_gui_cpp
[ 89%] Running SIP generator for qt_gui_cpp_sip Python bindings...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py", line 85, in <module>
    sip_dir, sip_flags = get_sip_dir_flags(config)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py", line 65, in get_sip_dir_flags
    raise FileNotFoundError('The sip directory for PyQt5 could not be located. Please ensure' +
NameError: global name 'FileNotFoundError' is not defined
make[2]: *** [src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/build.make:90: sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/Makefile] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:566: src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

I have checked that PyQt5 is installed so I'm not sure how to fix this error.

Thanks for any help

Comment: How did you install pyqt5? Not sure, but https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/660 may be relevant

Answer (score 0):

I solved by installing this packages:

```
sudo apt-get install sip-dev pyqt5-dev python-sip-dev pyqt5-dev-tools
```